# Internal payroll showing promoted title, no change in salary

Tags: communication, management, salary

I recently noticed in my company’s internal payroll software that my job title had changed for an unknown amount of time. For anonymity, I’ll call the titles Engineer I and Engineer II.

Currently, my salary is that of an Engineer level I, with a sizable raise when moving up to level II. During our 2017 yearly reviews, I made the case for moving on to level II. At the time the message was that money was tight and nobody was getting raises, but that messaging was prior to the reviews themselves.

Shortly after I noticed, I shared this with a peer and their reaction was very strong that this was not right, that I should take it up with management immediately, and that it might even have legal implications, as other peers did in fact move to Engineer II at the end of last year.

What do I do? Am I letting my employer walk all over me? My employer has a history of letting things like this drag out.

Comment: Is the raise from I to II contractual or part of a union agreement ?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly - no one here can say specifically what's going on in your company. Some organisations have rigid pay structures and paybands with strict rules about how much each job title pays, and how quickly salaries can be increased. Other companies it's all pretty flexible and up to the manager.

Are you part of a union? If so - I would contact them and ask them to advise you about it.

If not - I would:

1. Talk to you manager about it. Ask them: 'Have I been promoted? Is there a corresponding payrise?'.
2. Talk to your colleagues and ask them if their job title has changed too.